# Understanding java class file

Tags: java

I came across [this](https://interviewmania.com/discussion/42707-java-programming-basic-syntax) question :

> How can we identify whether a compilation unit is class or interface from a .class file?

The answer given was "from java source file header", with explanation

> The Java source file contains a header that declares the type of class or interface, its visibility with respect to other classes, its name and any superclass it may extend, or interface it implements.

But I didn't find anything explaining how source file header dictates class or interface in any standard documentation. Wikipedia [says](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file) following about the magic number (which I found to be relevant) in the class file:

> `CAFEBABE` became the class file format, and `CAFEDEAD` was the persistent object format.

Can someone point me to document explaining in detail how class file tells whether it's for class or interface along with other details of class file?

Comment: Given this falls under the category of "basic syntax" questions, I have to assume that's a typo, and the question should have read _"...from a .java file?"_.

Comment: @andrewjames The way I undertood it is that OP is given a .class file with the .java source code and has to decide based on the later if the .class file contains an interface or a class.

Comment: As I understand from the source webpage, the question meant  given `.class` file tell whether it corresponds to `.java` file containing class or interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can we identify whether a compilation unit is class or interface from a **.class** file?

According to [Chapter 4. The class File Format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se14/html/jvms-4.html) of the [Java Virtual Machine Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se14/html/index.html):

> A class file consists of a single ClassFile structure:
>
> ```
> ClassFile {
>     u4             magic;
>     u2             minor_version;
>     u2             major_version;
>     u2             constant_pool_count;
>     cp_info        constant_pool[constant_pool_count-1];
>     u2             access_flags;
>     . . .
> ```

And:

> The value of the `access_flags` item is a mask of flags used to denote access permissions to and properties of this class or interface. The interpretation of each flag, when set, is:
>
> ```
> Flag Name      Value   Interpretation
> ACC_PUBLIC     0x0001  Declared public; may be accessed from outside its package.
> ACC_FINAL      0x0010  Declared final; no subclasses allowed.
> ACC_SUPER      0x0020  Treat superclass methods specially when invoked by the invokespecial instruction.
> ACC_INTERFACE  0x0200  Is an interface, not a class.
> . . .
> ```

So if the 2-byte `access_flags` value has bit 9 set, then it is an interface, otherwise it's a class.

Comment: yikes thats precise and unnecessarily extremely subtle for java interview question...(the source webpage lists it as MCQ sort of java interview questions)

Answer (score 0):

For example;

```
class a {
    ...
}

interface a {
    ...
}
```

Also, you can extend a class, or implement an interface.

When you extend a class you can use another classes all functions, and it writes like that:

```
class a extends JFrame {
    a() {
        setVisible(true); //a method for jframe
    }
}
```

When you use an interface you must implement it:

```
class b implements KeyListener {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { 

    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { 

    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

}
```